# About blockadblock script on amp version on the site

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, adblock

How to enable adblock detector and blocker on the mobile version of the website which is also known as “amp” version? I have enabled the blockadblock site code on my desktop version of my website but i am unable to add the blockadblock script in amp version of the same site. How to enable it? Site is built on Wordpress.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-ad-insert-on-amp-pages/). This code removes adinserter shortcode rendering from Better-AMP pages.
`add_shortcode('adinserter', '__return_false');`. You may also check with this [link](https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages-for-wordpress-and-woocommerce/16278608/comments?page=6) for reference.

Comment: I want to detect adblocker on the visitor’s computer . So give me the code suitable for amp site of Wordpress.

Comment: At the moment you can't. Client side scripts are a no-no at this point. The ideal thing to do right now is to place placeholder text behind ads to politely ask them to remove ad blockers.